# How to take input from user in dart?

Tags: dart

some changes in Dart 2.0 so refer this code.

```
void main() {
  int n = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!); // stdin.readLineSync() used for int value
  String? name = stdin.readLineSync()!; // stdin.readLineSync() used for String value
  print("enter name: ${name}");
  print("enter number: ${n}");
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? Can you specify the error you get?

Comment: Also, `stdin.readByteSync()` is not used to get a int value. Instead, you will get the next byte from standard input which is rarely what you want if you are making an interactive terminal application. Instead, you should use `stdin.readLineSync()` and parse the input to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  int n = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  String name = stdin.readLineSync(); 
  print("enter name: ${name}");
  print("enter number: ${n}");
}
```

Comment: // For int value
Stdin get stdin
dart:io

The standard input stream of data read by this program.

The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)

// String value
if I do for String, it successfully compiles but at run time it shows nothing.

Comment: Currect Answer.
put "!" mark at end of stdin.readLineSync()
EX: String name = stdin.readLineSync()!;
EX:int n = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);

Answer (score 0):

To take the string input you can use the following code

```
import "dart:io";
void main() {
  print("enter name:");
  String name = stdin.readLineSync()!;
  print("your name is: $name");
}
```

To take the integer input you can use the following code

```
import "dart:io";
void main() {
  print("enter number:");
  int number= int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
  print("number you entered is: $num");
}
```

To print the srting input in integer you can use the following code

```
import "dart:io";
void main() {
  print("enter string:");
  String str = stdin.readLineSync()!;
  print("number converted to int is ${int.parse(str)}");
}
```